# How to set the NSDate on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to ask 2 questions about the NSDate of iPhone application.

1) How to set the 
NSDate *startDay to 01-01-2010 and NSDate *endDay to 31-12-2010

2) how many day between the startDay and the endDay.

What should I do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For handling dates with different formats you would need to use `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
```

To get date with specified format

```
NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:date];
```

To create a date from string with specified format:

```
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString];
```

[NSDateFormatter documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To find the difference between two dates:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [endDay timeIntervalSinceDate:startDay];
```

[timeIntervalSinceDate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:)

Comment: thank you for your reply. But how to set the startDay and the endDay, I don't know how to set the date.